# Angularjs image preview without filereader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, filereader

Angularjs: Is there any way, where I can show the image preview to the user for the image selected by him,without using filereader.

Below is my code trying to for it

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile"/><br><br>
<button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
<img src = {{image}}>   

<script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);
      mainApp.controller('myController', function ($scope,$http) {
          $scope.uploadFile = function(){
          var file = $scope.myFile;
          var fd = new FormData();
         //fd will be an file object now, I want this to be converted to img 
          $scope.image = Resultimage;
          };
     });
     mainApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
     return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;
                element.bind('change', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                            }); //end of scope.$apply
                    });//end of link
                }
           };
     }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can set the $scope.image to equal URL.createObjectURL(file);

```
<script>
function readfile(el) {
    let file = el.files[0];
    document.getElementById("previewImage").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
</script>
<img id="previewImage">
<input type='file' onchange='readfile(this)'/>
```